# Slick2D: Key Released

Tags: java, input, keylistener, slick2d

Slick's `Input` class has a `isKeyPressed()` method that returns a boolean value according to whether the specified key has been pressed.  I'd like to implement a way to check if a key has been released in the same fashion.

I looked into adding a `KeyListener` to the input object, and overriding the `keyReleased()` method.  However, the way I am currently handling input is in the `update()` method of my `BasicGame`.  By implementing the aforementioned solution, I fracture my code and handle input in two different places which I'd like to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input doesn't have a keyReleased method because it is a polling type of class. It only holds a boolean value if the key had been pressed, and then relinquishes that value upon request of seeing if it was pressed by input.isKeyPressed(VK_KEY).

If you look at the InputTest example provided in the slick trunk by Kevin Glass, you will see that BasicGame, and BasicGameState both carry a method called isKeyPressed/isKeyReleased.

[InputTest.java Slick2D resource](https://bitbucket.org/kevglass/slick/src/tip/trunk/Slick/src/org/newdawn/slick/tests/InputTest.java)

These are the methods you are looking for, as they will provide you with more control over what happens when keys are pressed or released.